# conda environment can't find module torch

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-18.04, torch

Yesterday I created a conda environment on a Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04). The installation commands were as follows:

```
conda create --name yolov5 python=3.8.13
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

Then I installed `requirements.txt` with `pip` of [yolov5 repo](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5). Everything went smoothly and I even did an inference on a sample image. I also created a clone of that env as `conda create clone yolov5 --name yolov5-2`.

Today I was going to do some training on conda env `yolov5`. After activating it with `conda activate yolov5`, I ran the `train.py` with its arguments. However, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projects/yolov5/train.py", line 26, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

It looks like this conda env (`yolov5`) got linked to the base env. Because when I activate `yolov5` and type `python`, its version is 3.9.7 which is exactly the same with base env's python version. Besides, `yolov5-2` is running perfectly well, I could import torch without any issues.

Why did it happen?
How can I solve this?

Comment: show all the commands, including installing pip using conda

Comment: Conda doesn't automatically activate the venv after creation, any chance you created `yolov5` env but installed the packages on `base` env?

Comment: @Elia, no, I was careful with that. Besides, I cloned `yolov5` to `yolov5-2`, and it was working properly. Anyways, I had to uninstall everything and started from scratch.